# Memory issue while using PdfReader

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to read 250MB pdf  file using PdfReader but it is giving memory issue.

I already tried `PdfReader` with different constructor `PdfReader`(filename),`PdfReader` (`byte[]`),PdfReader (`inputstream`) but for all it is giving same error of memory problem of heap.

Is there any way to solve this issue. RAM of my PC is 4GB.

How to solve this issue so that it will work for pdf upto 1GB.

Comment: What you want to achieve by reading a huge file ? Can this file be broken before reading ?

Comment: Did you look into memory related JVM arguments? `xmx` etc

Comment: Have you tried the  PDFReader ( new RandomAccessFileOrArray( new FileInputStream(...);

Comment: @reto I already set xmx value as -Xms32M -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper: a 250 MB PDF file is considered "not that big" in the prepress world. And, yes, I have handled single page files of that size…

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the requirement you could use a partial read methodology which can reduce the amount of memory usage. Instead of reading the entire file into memory PdfReader (filename), PdfReader (byte[]), PdfReader (inputstream) , You could try the following instead.

new PDFReader ( new RandomAccessFileOrArray( new FileInputStream(...),null);

Also I think you wanted to know if there is a way to improve the memory usage through coding,not by increasing the heap size,for which you can use -xms and -xmx flags

Comment: It is giving error on this line new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(new FileInputStream(new File(sourcefile))));

no suitable constructor found for PdfReader(RandomAccessFileOrArray)
    constructor PdfReader.PdfReader(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; RandomAccessFileOrArray cannot be converted to String)
    constructor PdfReader.PdfReader(byte[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; RandomAccessFileOrArray cannot be converted to byte[])

Comment: I believe you are using itext ? if so which version ?

Comment: @ The Neo Noir Developer yes you are correct i am using itext 5.5.4

Comment: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray, byte[]). Things would have changed in between. :) 

If it worked let me know I would update the answer

Comment: Yes I already tried this and i mentioned this in Question also. but it is not working for huge file. 200MB onwards

Comment: I think you did not read the link , there is public PdfReader(RandomAccessFileOrArray raf, byte[] ownerPassword). Which am sure you did not try.

Comment: @ The Neo Noir Developer Thanks it works.
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0',
                    null, true);

 but on this line  it is giving java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: What is the current heap space given , and what is the file size you are reading ?

Comment: Memory set : -Xms32M -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
And pdf file size 245MB

Comment: set both to 1024M and run, observe, change it back to the older code and observe the change.

Comment: It is taking much time to execute new PdfReader(inputstream) this line and giving same error.

Comment: How about the memory ? Right now with the RandomAccessFileOrArray  it looks like it is taking around 5 times the file size.

Comment: PdfReader(String filename, byte[] ownerPassword, boolean partial) i use this code and it works . i set partial value true. but i am not understanding what is meaning of reading file partially. It may cause loss of data?

Comment: *not understanding what is meaning of reading file partially. It may cause loss of data* - No. iText merely only loads the parts of the PDF currently in use into memory. No need to load all at once as long as you know where to retrieve the data just in time.